# Is there a maximum time one can hold postdoc positions between the PhD and the more permanent positions in Mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, career-path, sweden, finland

As the title suggests, I wonder for how long one can hold postdoc positions after having done the PhD (specifically Mathematics, where I am currently a finishing PhD-student). In other words; is there any limitation on the length of the "postdoc-phase"?

I know that in some fields and some Universities they have a maximum time span (e.g. applicant cannot have finished their PhD more than three years ago), but believe myself to have seen counter-examples to this; e.g. someone had been a postdoc effectively for 12 years before landing a permanent position (lecturer, or so), but I could have misunderstood this.

Comment: Which country are you based in?

Comment: Northern Europe - either Sweden, Norway or Finland.

Comment: Going to be different university to university, even prof to prof. Some profs don't want to see anybody doing more than "some small number of years." (In the range 2 or 4 or such.) Others are happy to keep paying a post doc for two decades.

Comment: Isn't Erdős a fairly strong counterexample to this question?

Comment: I knew someone from Eastern Europe that had been an eternal postdoc for something like 10 years, constantly going from one temporary position to the next.  Not sure why as they had some good papers.

Comment: @Tom - while a postdoc is a temporary position, not all temporary positions are postdocs.

Comment: @Tom - because the system isn't deterministic and other factors can often determine whether people get a stable job or not, uncorrelated with the perceived quality of their work.

Answer (score 19):

Single data point for Mathematics, Austria:

I have been "postdoc" (funded by my own research projects) for 18 years or so before finally getting a permanent job. I have some excellent colleagues who still have no permanent position after a comparable time as postdocs.

The reason for this situation is that (in Austria, in Mathematics) it has been very hard to get permanent positions in the last 20 years or so, and much easier to get research projects. And life for the eternal postdocs now gets even harder due to new chain contract rules (you are not allowed to work in a non-permanent job at any given university for more than 8 years in total.)

Comment: Can I ask why in Austria researchers can't keep a non-permanent job for more than 8 years? Is it a common practice in academia? It sounds scary

Comment: It is supposed to protect people from being exploited by being employed perpetually without having a proper, permanent job. The theory is: either you are so good that the university wants you, then they should give you a proper job. Or you are not, then they should not lead you on by giving you new temporary jobs every few years.

Comment: @Amelian This is common in Europe (although the details vary by country), based on https://eur-lex.europa.eu/EN/legal-content/summary/fixed-term-work.html , but I wouldn't call that recent, unless Austria was late in adopting this European directive.

Comment: There were some chain contract rules before, but until a year ago they were easy to get around:  You could reset your "counter" at a university by working at another one for at least a year. Now,  your total lifetime employment counts.

Answer (score 14):

I certainly know one person (in mathematics) who has functioned as a paid researcher for 20+ years and still does not have a permanent position. I’m not sure they are called a “postdoc” any more, but they take time-limited paid research positions. Very frustrating as they are immensely competent.

I also know of someone in physics in roughly the same situation although they did find a non-permanent but somewhat stable position in a research centre: at least there's hope the funding will be renewed for the next few years so they don't have to move every 2nd or 3rd year.

Comment: As academia is indoctrinated with the culture of success, a failure to secure a permanent position (or to reach other constantly shifting goalposts) quickly becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: And this is within Mathematics?

Comment: @Vertex yes it is.

Answer (score 12):

This is a North American answer.

There is no strict time limit for most positions, but most positions will have a preference for applicants that are closer to their PhDs.  How strong this preference is varies from position to position and even from search committee to search committee.  However, the general result is that it becomes harder and harder to get a postdoc the farther you are from your PhD.  Getting hired as a postdoc 10 years after your PhD would be very unlikely though it happens.

Comment: Is this true even if you've been working in research for those 10 years and have a decent track record of publishing good science? This answer makes sense if you spend 10 years in industry, but I doubt it holds true if you've got good experience to prove your competency and just haven't elected to take a permanent position for one reason or another

Comment: @ScottishTapWater: It is absolutely true and your doubts are unfounded.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater: Keep in mind that, in many ways, theoretical mathematics is a humanities discipline, and researchers don't generally need help on their projects in the same way as in the sciences or engineering.  Speaking cynically, when you hire a postdoc (or take on a grad student), it's so that you have one more person in the community who will be influenced by your research and hence cite it for the rest of their career.  Researchers who have a longer track record are more likely to stick to their own research agenda rather than being heavily influenced by yours.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater If you have 5 years of postdoc experience you should realize postdocs do not pay very well.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo - That sounds like hiring processes for postdocs are fundamentally unsound then?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater:  I mean, most hiring processes in academia are unsound, so it should come as no surprise that the hiring processes for postdocs are unsound.

Answer (score 6):

In general, there is no time limit. Some governmental funding sources do limit their postdoc funding with rules, e.g. only people who finished their PhD within the last 5 years might apply, etc. But this is not strictly a limit on how many postdocs you can do or how long you can be a postdoc, but a limit on getting those specific grants.

Keep in mind that these days "postoc" just means "job you get after the PhD." Yes, many postdocs, esp. grant-funded positions work as almost independent PIs hosted by an institution, while at the other end of the spectrum you have postdocs who are just underpaid teachers and technicians, and everything in between.

One of my grad school mentors was a postdoc for 20+ years and died (heart attack, old age) while still being a postdoc. So there's that.

Comment: Yes, there's a qualitative difference between getting a research fellowship through a grant you yourself submit as the sole applicant, before getting a stable position, and being employed by someone else via money they got from applying for a grant. This is before taking into account the need or otherwise to teach.

Answer (score 5):

The German answer:

In Germany, Universities are by law not allowed to hand out temporary contracts indefinitely and either have to give you a permanent position or not employ you at all (if you did not manage to get tenure in time, this means the latter). This is the infamous **Wissenschaftszeitvertragsgesetz** or **WissZeitVG**.

Rougly, that means that the time as a postdoc after the PhD is in principle limited to **12 years minus the time of your phd** (e.g. 4 postdocs of 2-year length if your phd took 4 years).

The main way around this is working abroad, which does not count towards the 6 years. There are some more exceptions in Germany (third party projects, working directly towards habilitation etc.?), but I'm not so sure how this works in practice.

So there's a severe timer on your career which is why going abroad at least once is often a necessity and many end their academic career even after 10+ years as a postdoc.

---

Note: I'm not an expert on this, so please let me know if I got something wrong. But I thought this special circumstance deserved to be mentioned.

Comment: Please note that the penultimate paragraph (*"which is why long PhDs with more possibility to publish are seen as favorable"*) is not correct as currently worded: if you take less than six years to complete your PhD, the difference (between six years and the time you actually took for the PhD) is added to the six years that you have after your PhD. So taking more time for the PhD doesn't give you an advantage in this regard.

Comment: Ah, WissZeitVG, the bureaucrats' answer to Schroedinger's problem :/

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thanks for pointing that out! I edited the answer.